# How to get the login id of a user logged in remote computer?

Tags: c#, windows, tasklist

I am using the following code to get the current logged in user through remote desktop

```
  public string connect(string machineName)
        {
                System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
                System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
                startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                string command = "/C tasklist /v /fo list /fi \"imagename eq explorer.exe\" /s " + machineName;
                startInfo.Arguments = command;
                process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                process.Start();
                string strOutput = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                if(strOutput.Contains("\\"))
                {
                int qindex = strOutput.IndexOf("\\");
                int rindex = strOutput.IndexOf("\r", qindex);
                string substring = strOutput.Substring((qindex + 1), (rindex - qindex));
                return substring;
                }
        }
```

But this process is taking unusually long time (more than 1 min)  to get the remote user name. I cant run wmic since RPC is not enabled in the remote computer.

I also tried the following

```
    string UNC = "\\\\";
    UNC += machineName;
    UNC += "\\C$\\Users";
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(UNC);
    DirectoryInfo[] dirs = di.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
    var Myfile = dirs.OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime).First();
```

But this not always reliable because the user name directory is not getting updated even though the user is logged in.

Is there any simpler process to get the remote user name

Comment: "unusually long time"?  What is "usual"?

Comment: it is taking more than 1 min

Comment: Cant you remotely start RPC?

Comment: @CaptainAnon its blocked in firewall. I cant change the rules